# Handling an exception within Room

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I migrated from ormlite to Android Room

I use custom query which can fail, but I don't find how to handle the exception

```
try {
  appDatabase.query(new SimpleSQLiteQuery(sql));
} catch (SQLException e)
{
  // custom code
}
```

how can i achieve this with android rooms ?

That type of query fail with some version of sqlite

```
INSERT INTO country(id,continent,name)
SELECT 1,'Asia','Afghanistan' UNION 
SELECT 2,'Africa','Egypt'
```

of course there are a lot of line, and it was made for performance reasons. If it fail, I run a fail sql batch

that type of query is supported from a sqlite version BUT there are device which don't support it, even it has the required version. (so I'd like to know when there is an error)

Comment: What do you exactly expect to happen when you get that exception?

Comment: "I use custom query which can fail" What do you mean with fail? Does it throw an exception? Also, why are you using a "custom query" where you can also rely on Rooms compile-time query checking?

Comment: Write test cases for that custom query. Also define what to do when your query fails.

Comment: it may fail depending of the sqlite version. and even the version isn't reliable to avoid it. I have optimised query which work for 98% of the device and fail over query, is it possible to catch sql exception in android rooms to handle that case ?

Comment: how did you solve this problem?

Comment: no issue. had to rewrite it to make it 100% compliant sorry